# PHP - Sort array with mixed types

Tags: php

I have a php array with mixed types like this :

```
  $length = array (15, 3, 5, '-');
```

and I want to sort it to obtain a list of values sorted like this : '-', 3, 5, 15

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, When using various mixed type in an array , you would need to set your own "priorities" of whats first and whats last.

You could use PHP's [usort](http://il.php.net/usort) function to define your own function to sort the array and define your own priorities for each data type or value.

Shai.

Comment: Thanks, in my case the first item should be alwas '-' and then a normal numbers sort (low to high).

Comment: Ok , so just check if your array contains a dash, if yes remove it from the array, sort the array using the regular sort() and than push the dash in the beginning of the array. Shouldn't be complicated at all.

Comment: In that case, normal sort() function will give you the desired result

Comment: I wrote a big long example for no need, as Vikk correctly said, the regular sort() would do just fine :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use usort, because PHP's sort function is not stable. See http://quaxio.com/wtf/php.html#turtle17